# generic max jstl function

Tags: java, generics

I need a max function in my jstl, so i am writing a static function and exposing it in the tld as a jstl function.

The problem is, i dont know what type the arguments will be, int, long, double etc. Do i have to create a function for each data type? 
or
Maybe i can just write the function for doubles, and pray that jstl will do the conversion for me?

**edit2**:
nevermind, i thought the tld definition would be as simple as T max(T,T) but this is not the case. i have no idea how to make a tld definition for the generic method. I guess ill just pray that the jsp will convert my type correctly and use Math.max(double, double)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a max function like `Math.max()` (take two parameters, return the greater), or something like `Arrays.sort()` (take an array, return the greatest).

In the first case, JSP EL will coerce the arguments to the correct types if it is possible.

In the second case, a distinct method is needed for each primitive array component type you want to support.

Comment: its a math.max function. actually, i really wanted to use varags but it looks like jsp2.0 doesnt support those as jstl function arguments :P

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(T a, T b) {
    if (a.compareTo(b) > 0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(max(20, 10));
    System.out.println(max(103.2, 120.2));
    // it works even on strings...
    System.out.println(max("aaa", "bbb"));  
    // ... and booleans...
    System.out.println(max(true, false));  
}
```

in alternative you can use standard Java classes like `Collections` and `Arrays`:

```
Collections.max(Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40, 50));
```

Comment: ill try that as soon as i figure out how to write a jslt function declaration for that =)